# Family tracking app

Tags: android, tracking

I need a family tracking app that:

- Free;
- Has emergency button (prefferrably on the first page);
- Doesn't require login beyond phone number;
- Lightweight.

Anyone ?

Answer (score 3):

[Life360](https://www.life360.com/) - been using it for years and they've really improved battery performance/usage.

Free, but also has paid version for more options.

Has safety features for road side assistance or to trigger a help alert.

Manage "circles" of people, who can see each other.  Multiple different circles allowed.

And with the push of a button, get directions to someone in your circle.

Comment: Probably the best. Could have the emergency button on the first page though. And could be lighter (there are apps of the kind with 3 MB - this one takes 30). If no better answer appear soon, yours is it.

Answer (score 1):

There are some Google solutions I think might help.

*Edit: they all need a Google Account (Login) so it doesn't meet all your requirements.*

- Google Maps has also a "share location" function, but not an "emergency button"
- [Probably preinstalled Google function called family link](https://support.google.com/families/answer/7103413)
- [Google Trusted Contacts Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.emergencyassist)